# RestTemplate not working with S3 pre-signed put URLs

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, resttemplate

I have a server generate AWS S3 pre-signed PUT URLs and then I'm trying to uploading a `byte[]` into that URL using RestTemplate with this code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));
HttpEntity<byte[]> entity = new HttpEntity<>("Testing testing testing".getBytes(), headers);
System.out.println(restTemplate.exchange(putUrl, HttpMethod.PUT, entity, String.class));
```

When I run that code, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
    at tech.dashman.dashman.controllers.RendererAppController.lambda$null$2(RendererAppController.java:95)
```

Unfortunately, there's nothing in the AWS S3 logs, so, I'm not sure what's going on. If I take that exact same URL and put it in the REST Client of IntelliJ IDEA, it just works (it creates an empty file in S3).

Any ideas what's wrong with my Java code?

Here's a full example that does the signing and tries to uploading a small payload to S3:

```
import com.amazonaws.HttpMethod;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GeneratePresignedUrlRequest;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import java.util.Date;

public class S3PutIssue {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        String awsAccessKeyId = "";
        String awsSecretKey = "";
        String awsRegion = "";
        String path = "";
        String awsBucketName = "";
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretKey);
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(awsRegion).
                withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).build();
        Date expiration = new DateTime().plusDays(1).toDate();
        GeneratePresignedUrlRequest urlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(awsBucketName, path);
        urlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
        urlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);
        String putUrl = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(urlRequest).toString();

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        HttpEntity<byte[]> entity = new HttpEntity<>("Testing testing testing".getBytes(), headers);
        restTemplate.exchange(putUrl, org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.PUT, entity, Void.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: From what you describe I can imagine that your code doesn’t generate the very same call as REST client of IDEA does. I can recommend to set the log level such that you see underlying HTTP related logs to see what exactly is sent - I expect it’s some difference in headers. Also, does your code work if you don’t use signing of PUTs?

Comment: @Xonix: how do I increase the logging output for RestTemplate? I think that the requests being different is almost certain, but I cannot find the difference.

Comment: What do you mean by "pre-signed" URL?

Comment: @JoseMartinez: here's Amazon's documentation on pre-signing S3 URLs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Comment: Could you provide minimal working code sample with `main` which produces this error?

Comment: @NikitaGorbachevski: I'm not sure what you expect, S3 signing? It's a bit involved and it would require setting up an S3 bucket, AWS, credentials, etc.

Comment: I would like to get a minimal code snippet to reproduce the error, cause your current sample works fine on my tests. Is it possible to provide it omitting all private/configurable information (keys,bucket,objectId) ?

Comment: @NikitaGorbachevski Something like that?

Comment: @Pablo if your are working with logback, you can log more info about RestTemplate simply by adding `<logger name="org.springframework.web.client"><level value="DEBUG"/></logger>` to your logback.xml. Make sure you have no filter in your appender or it has at least DEBUG level

Comment: @Pablo yes, thank you, will try to reproduce/investigate this issue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The source of issue is a double encoding of url characters. There are `/` in extended secret key which are encoded as `%2` by `s3Client.generatePresignedUrl`. When already encoded string is passed to `restTemplate.exchange` it's internally converted to URI and encoded for the second time as `%252` by `UriTemplateHandler` in `RestTemplate` source code.

```
@Override
@Nullable
public <T> T execute(String url, HttpMethod method, @Nullable RequestCallback requestCallback,
        @Nullable ResponseExtractor<T> responseExtractor, Object... uriVariables) throws RestClientException {

    URI expanded = getUriTemplateHandler().expand(url, uriVariables);
    return doExecute(expanded, method, requestCallback, responseExtractor);
}
```

So the easiest solution is to convert URL to URI using `URL.toURI()`. If you don't have `URI` and have `String` when `RestTemplate` is invoked then two options are possible.

Pass URI instead for string to exchange method.

```
restTemplate.exchange(new URI(putUrl.toString()), HttpMethod.PUT, entity, Void.class);
```

Create default `UriTemplateHandler` with `NONE` encoding mode and pass it to `RestTemplate`.

```
DefaultUriBuilderFactory defaultUriBuilderFactory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
defaultUriBuilderFactory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);
restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(defaultUriBuilderFactory);
restTemplate.exchange(putUrl.toString(), org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.PUT, entity, Void.class);
```

Comment: the `DefaultUriBuilderFactory` was added in Spring 5. Do you have any recommendation for Spring 4.3? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: A 6+ year old answer saved my butt!  I was banging my head against the desk trying to figure this out!  URI fixed it for me!

Answer (score 5):

Do not convert your URL to String.  Instead convert it to URI.  I think there are some encoding issues when you converted to String.  For example the URL in String format had `%252F`, where it should have just been `%2F`.  Looks like some sort of double encoding issue.

Leave as URL...

```
     URL putUrl = amazonS3Client.generatePresignedUrl(urlRequest);
```

Convert to URI...

```
    ResponseEntity<String> re = restTemplate.exchange(putUrl.toURI(), org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.PUT, entity, String.class);
```

EDIT:  More info to clarify what is going on.

The problem that occurred here is that when you call `URL.toString()` in this instance you are given back an encoded String representation of the URL.  But the RestTemplate is expecting a String url that is not yet encoded.  RestTemplate will do the encoding for you.

For example look at the code below...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
    rt.exchange("http://foo.com/?var=<val>", HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, String.class);
}
```

When you run this you get the following debug message from Spring, notice how the url in the debug msg is encoded.

```
[main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Created GET request for "http://foo.com/?var=%3Cval%3E"
```

So you can see the RestTemplate will encode for you any String url's passed to it.  But the URL provided by AmazonS3Client is already encoded.  See the code below.

```
URL putUrl = amazonS3Client.generatePresignedUrl(urlRequest);
System.out.println("putUrl.toString = " + putUrl.toString());
```

This prints out a String that is already encoded.

```
https://private.s3.amazonaws.com/testing/?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20171114T191829Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=0&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIJ7ZSL22IJTM6NTQ%2F20171114%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=eca611ea33d9ad5710207568dcf181e4318ce39271fd0f1ce05bd99ebbf4097
```

So when I stick that into the exchange method of the RestTemplate I get the following debug message.

```
[main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - PUT request for "https://turretmaster.s3.amazonaws.com/testing/?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20171114T191829Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=0&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIJ7ZSL22IJTM6NTQ%252F20171114%252Fus-east-1%252Fs3%252Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=eca611ea33d9ad5710207568dcf181e4318ce39271fd0f1ce05bd99ebbf40975"
```

Notice how every `%2F` from the url String turned into `%252F`.  `%2F` is the encoded representation of `/`.  But `%25` is `%`.  So it encoded a url that was already encoded.  The solution was to pass a `URI` object to `RestTemplate.exchange`, instead of an encoded String url.

Comment: That's definitely a good find, but that putUrl has to be a string. It's generated on the server and put in the database and then sent as JSON to the client which does the actual PUT.

Comment: If I print that url string, copy and paste it into IntelliJ's REST Client, it works, so, I don't think it's mangled up to that point.

Comment: Did you try it?  I'm telling you I copied and pasted your code, reproduced the problem, then made the change I mentioned, and the problem is fixed.  When I copied and pasted the String url from the RestTemplate debug (not the postUrl String), it had double encoding.  Thats the String url I used to reproduce using Postman on Chrome.

Comment: @Pablo, so unless this didn't work, can you mark this as correct and provide the 500 bounty?  I worked on this and solved it because there was a bounty.  I think the answer I provided is correct.  Its a simple encoding issue.

Comment: @Pablo i do not think it is fair that you gave the bounty to someone who provided the same answer that I already provided.  Not cool bro.